# table paste in memo form of lotus notes

Tags: excel, lotusscript

I have Excel Report in which there is table as shown below 
Table_capture From Excel Report
[image]

And on click of'send' button, the lotus script copy this picture and paste it a memo and send to respective user. It is working fine in my Pc but in USer PC the color in the table disappears as shown below 
UserPC_Table_Capture
[image] 
For your Info, User is using same EXcel version as mine but PC of user is Yoga laptop,mine is Thinkpad T460. please help

Comment: Have you checked the color palette or screen settings match between the machines?

Comment: Please help me to how to check and set color palette on the machines?